# What is the loss of the test antenna connected to the spectrum analyser?

Tags: rf, antenna, pcb-antenna, spectrum-analyzer

I am testing the gain and radiation pattern of some PCB antennas and have a Siglent SSA-3032X-R spectrum analyser connected to a Tekbox Biconical TBMA1 measurement antenna. The test set up and antenna is shown below.

[image: Test set up]

[image: Biconical measurement antenna TBMA1]

The Device Under Test (DUT) is 1m from the antenna (not able to show the DUT in the image).

I have measured the gain at various angles around the DUT and plotted this on a radial diagram to show its radiation pattern. For example, I have measured -30dBm in the XY place at 0°.

The test antenna itself will have a loss however. How can I determine the loss if the antenna so that I can factor this out of the radiated power measured from the DUT?

Comment: Hum ... You are not in "open-air" with that heating radiator behind ... and some "reflections" occur which are probably "disturbing" measures.

Comment: What does the antenna's data sheet tell you?

Comment: To be sure you are in "open-air", make a measurement when "DUT" is off. If you see "something", except the "noise ground", then there is "signal disturbance" ...

Answer (score 2):

The gain or loss of the TBMA test antenna, compared to an isotropic antenna, is specified in its datasheet (I've attached the chart from that datasheet below). You use the Friis path loss equation to convert the measurement to get absolute gain/loss of your DUT.

(Friis equation from Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friis_transmission_equation )

[image: Friis equation]

Your known values include the Pr (receive power in dBm, indicated on spectrum analyzer), Pt (transmit power in dBm for your DUT), and the Dr (receive antenna gain in dBi). You can then solve for the unknown Dt (transmit antenna gain in dBi).

But you can't get an accurate antenna radiation pattern measurement inside an ordinary room. The proper way is to place both antennas inside an anechoic chamber -- a room lined with RF absorber material, and shielded from outside signals. You must have your antennas separated by several wavelengths so you are in the far field.

A "poor man's" approach to measuring the pattern is to place both antennas outdoors, several wavelengths above the ground, and use insulated poles (PVC pipe or wood) to support them. Rotate the DUT to get the pattern in the horizontal plane. If you want the pattern in the vertical plane, mount them both vertically and repeat the measurements.

Datasheet: https://www.tekbox.com/product/TBMA1_Manual.pdf

[image: Biconical measurement antenna gain]

Comment: The datasheet specifies the Isotropic gain of the test antenna is ~=-3.5dBi for the frequency of interest (~868MHz). I am measuring in dBm so how can I factor in a loss of -3dBi when all of the results from the spectrum analyser are in dBm?

Comment: I've edited my answer to explain exactly how to use the path loss equation in your situation.